# Crear un json con informacion de dos arrays distintos que se cargan por DOM

Tags: javascript, local-storage, jsonarray

tengo dos class para poder ingresar datos en dos Form, a través del DOM.

// Sección carga de Usuario

```
`class Usuario {
    constructor (nombre, apellido, email, telefono){
        this.nombre = nombre
        this.apellido = apellido
        this.email = email
        this.telefono = telefono
    }
}`
```

//   Sección carga de datos clientes y listado

```
`class Cliente {
    constructor (usuarionombre, denominacion, digitocuit, mescierre, iva, ganancias){
        this.usuario = usuarionombre
        this.denominacion = denominacion
        this.digitocuit = digitocuit
        this.mescierre = mescierre
        this.iva = iva
        this.ganancias = ganancias
    }
}`
```

Mi intencion es que en un seccion se puedan dar de alta tantos usuarios como se desee y en la segunda seccion (Cliente) solo puedan darse de alta si previamente asigno un usuario (  this.nombre = nombre). Si este campo no esta cargado previamente (en el Local Storage), entonces no lo deja ingresar un usuario.

Hecho esto, quisiera crear un LS donde por cada usuario se incuyan todos los clientes que ingreso.

Intente varias opciones pero nada funciono. Alguien tiene alguna idea para compartirme?

Muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Agrego mas datos a mi consulta: a) Primero deberia poner una verificacion previa al momento de cargar un nuevo Cliente. Si no ingreso un nombre de Usuario y ese nombre no esta previamente registrado en el LocalStorage, no deberia dejarme avanzar. b) Si a) se cumple, deberia crearme un nuevo array que se suba a LS donde por cada nombre de Usuario me muestra los Clientes que creo.

Comment: Podrías compartir lo que has intentado?

Comment: Al cargar Cliente siemprte requiere nombre.usuario.                                                                                                                                        
    `class Cliente {
    constructor (usuarionombre, denominacion, digitocuit, mescierre, iva, ganancias){
        this.usuario = usuarionombre
        this.denominacion = denominacion
        this.digitocuit = digitocuit
        this.mescierre = mescierre
        this.iva = iva
        this.ganancias = ganancias
    }
}` Pero no se como validar que usuario este previamente cargado